# Excel VBA or Script to run the same macro (refreshes data connection from 1 file & repeats on other files in the same directory)

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm searching for a code to run the same macro on 200+ files in the same folder directory until the last file is complete.

The macro I have currently does this once I click a button

1. Refresh .CSV data connection (File Selection window pops up in
       the directory, I select the file)
2. Refreshes Pivot Table
3. Deletes Specific Tabs
4. Saves Copy As in another Directory

**I want to eliminate me clicking the RUN button 200+ times, and selecting the .CSV file.  Would anyone happen to know of a code that could do this?**

**Current MACRO is:**

```
Sub Load_Brand3()

 ' Load_Brand3 Macro

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("DATATable[[#Headers],[Datetime]]").Select
Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
Sheets("Brand Summary").Select
Range("A13").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Retailer.Name").ShowDetail _
    = False
Sheets("Brand Summary").Select 

Dim SavedCopy As Excel.Workbook

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\ME" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & "-" & [A1] & ".xlsm"
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\ME" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & "-" & [A1] & ".xlsm"

Set SavedCopy = ActiveWorkbook

With SavedCopy
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("BrandExport").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
.Worksheets("Lookup").Delete
.Worksheets("Count").Delete
Sheets("Brand Summary").Select
Range("A1").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
.Close True

End With

MsgBox ("Your File was saved.")

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried Macro Recorder for the full process once and then look at the code and go from there? If the CSV files name are of some pattern, you can automate it. You should create the code in a separate file which can log which files have been "Refreshed".

Answer (score 0):

This should be close.  Just change `MyPath` to the correct directory and run `ProcessFiles`.

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Const MyPath As String = "C:\Users\best buy\Data Files\*.csv"
    Dim FileName As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    FileName = Dir(MyPath, vbDirectory)
    Do While FileName <> ""
        Load_BrandFile FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub

Sub Load_BrandFile(FileName As String)
    Dim SavedCopy As Workbook
    Dim DATATable As ListObject
    Dim PivotTable1 As PivotTable

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\ME" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & "-" & [A1] & ".xlsm"
    Set SavedCopy = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ME" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & "-" & [A1] & ".xlsm")

    With SavedCopy
        Set DATATable = .Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("DATATable")
        DATATable.Refresh

        Set PivotTable1 = .Worksheets("Brand Summary").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        PivotTable1.PivotCache.Connection = FileName
        PivotTable1.PivotFields("Retailer.Name").ShowDetail = False

        .Connections("BrandExport").Delete
        .Worksheets("Lookup").Delete
        .Worksheets("Count").Delete
        Application.Goto Reference:=.Worksheets("Brand Summary").Range("A1"), scroll:=True
        .Close True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this sorts it for you.

```
Sub CycleFolder()

Dim folderSelect As FileDialog

Set folderSelect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With folderSelect
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    strItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Files = Dir(strItem & "\")

While Files <> ""
  'RUN FUNCTION HERE
  'Uncomment next line to test iteration
  'Debug.Print Files
  Files = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was unable to get this to work, I'll have to tinker with it some more.